# Convert Flatten CSV to nested JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I want to nest JSON from flatten CSV file, how to create a parent category using all the subcategories in flatten CSV file. Please check out the format of data in given image below.
[Image of the formats are in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFuY6.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can read about csv module here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

There is a class there called DictReader which takes a CSV file and puts it in a dictionary, and from there the way to json is easy.

The following example is presented there:

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

**Output:**

`Eric Idle John Cleese`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! I'm looking to make a nested json using category levels under one parent category. Can you check the image in the question please?

Comment: if the json is nested, then how do you expect the csv would look like? csv is table-based so i cant imagine how you would show nested data in the csv. if you are looking for ways to save the json data in a file you could use json.dumps() and json.loads() functions

Comment: I want the CSV data into nested JSON format, please check this image link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFuY6.jpg

Comment: in the example you gave i dont see cleaning-chemichals in the csv (so i dont know how it looks in the csv - for instance where did the value of ["parents"]["level1"]["$oid"] come from). in any case, this seems like a specific issue so i would take the csv data and change it mannualy to a nested json by the rules you decide.

Comment: I will be mapping that level1 id with MongoDB parent objectID and in nested JSON it's just the format sorry for mismatch of names. Problem is I've to convert like 1000s time manually. Can we group them and row by row put into a dictionary or a list?